# unset $_SESSION var reappears after refresh

Tags: php, session, unset

I am trying to use session to display a possible error msg. In my auth_id.php file, I checked whether the input id and password posted from auth_form.php file are correct, if not $_SESSION['fail'] will be set to an error msg.

At the top of my auth_id.php file, I checked whether $_SESSION['fail'] was set, if so, display the error msg and then unset $_SESSION['fail'].

But this is not working like what I expected. The unset function does remove 'fail' from $_SESSION in the auth_form.php file, but it reappears after refreshing the page. Therefore, I always got the error msg after setting it for the first time.

I am not sure what's causing this problem, anyone has any ideas what I did wrong?

Thank you for your help!
auth_form.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['fail'])) {
    print($_SESSION['fail']);
    unset($_SESSION['fail']);
}
?>
```

auth_id.php:

```
session_start();
$mode = $_SESSION['mode'];
if ($res->num_rows == 1) {
    // unset($_SESSION['fail']);
    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
    $db_password = $row['password'];
    if ($password == $db_password) {
        if ($mode == 'delete') {
            $delete = "DELETE FROM guestbook WHERE ID = $ID";
            $mysqli->query($delete);
            $_SESSION['delete'] = $row['name'] . "\'s comment has been deleted.";
            header("Location: list.php");
            die();
        }

    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
    $_SESSION['url'] = $row['url'];
    $_SESSION['comments'] = $row['comments'];

    header("Location: form.php");
    die();

} else {
    $_SESSION['fail'] = "Authentication failed.";
    header("Location: auth_form.php");
    die();
}
```

}

Comment: `unset` must remove the `key` value of fail variable. But refreshing showing it again..? try to `echo '<pre>';print_r($_SESSION)` to view all session vars

Comment: After posting this, I tried to create a whole new file to test if that unset works, and it did. Then I edited the auth_form.php file to put these codes on the very top of that file, now it works...